# matplotlib.pyplot.scatter does not respect mask rules with datetime

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, masked-array

matplotlib version `3.5.3`

Plotting a numpy masked array against a list of datetime objects, `plt.plot` functions as expected, but `plt.scatter` still displays the masked data. Auto-axis limits *do* respect the masked data though.

**Minimum working example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from datetime import datetime

# Create a list of datetime objects
time_unmasked = [datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 52),
                 datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 53),
                 datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 54),
                 datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 55),
                 datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 56),
                 datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 57),
                 datetime(2022, 11, 24, 4, 49, 58)]

# Create a masked array with three masked variables, one datapoint far from others
data_masked = ma.array([15,14,50,15,15,15,16], mask=[0,0,1,1,1,0,0])

# Line plot (expected behaviour)
plt.plot(time_unmasked, data_masked)
plt.show()

# Scatter plot (plots masked points, but ignores masked values when auto-setting axis limits)
plt.scatter(time_unmasked, data_masked)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

It seems as though there is a check within `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` that is not catching. I'd expect that logic to check that if either `x` or `y` were masked, to not plot that point. The datetime object is able to slip through. I've also tried putting `time_unmasked` within a numpy masked array with the same mask as `masked_data` (so both `x` and `y` have the same mask), but the same unexpected behaviour occurs.

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: do you get a different result if you plot against a numeric axis, e.g. `arange(7)` in the example?

Comment: yes—I get the 'normal' expected behaviour (only 4 scatterplot points show) if I plot against `arange(7)`. So I think the list of datetime objects is the cause, and is somehow able to slip past the scatterplot mask logic.

Comment: I can confirm this, and seems to be a bug in scatter.  Please report to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib. In the meantime, instead of using masks, you could set the bad data to NaN.

Comment: Have reported the issue here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24545